# Branch.io Channel, Ad Name, Link ID are all "unpopulated". Where could these clicks and installs come from?

Tags: analytics, branch.io

On Branch Analytics, Channel, Ad Name, Link ID are all showing "unpopulated". Trying to understand how to categorize these numbers. Does this mean all of these are from organic traffic from app store or browser google search? Also, what is an example of a "direct traffic"?

[image: screenshot from branch]

I've tried other dimensions and they all come back as "unpopulated". This group is the largest contributor to our installs so I'm trying to understand how to define it. Should I consider it all Organic?

Comment: Unpopulated can show up due to multiple reasons like if you are using a Branch link that doesn't have these analytical labels added to it. However, can you upload a complete Dashboard page screenshot here?

Comment: @KartikShandilya Apologies for the delayed reply, I didn't get a notification. Here's a dashboard screenshot:

Comment: @KartikShandilya Here's the screenshot: https://imgur.com/FSLvQkc

Comment: @KartikShandilya i'm also facing something similar, we are running facebook ads using branch ad links but in analytics the ad partner name and campaign name is unpopulated